# How to run a TFS build using gated check in, then a classic continous integration build?

Tags: tfs, build-process

I'm using TFS2013.

Do you know if there is a way to chain a gated check-in build, then a classic continuous integration build?

I currently have only one gated check-in build doing 2 actions. The problem is that the 2nd action cannot be done if the source code has not been effectively checked-in.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...
Thanks in advance for your help.

For those who are interrested in knowing the 2 actions I try to do:

1. get shelved code, check code quality and compilation (classic gated check-in).
2. get latest source code, compile it, copy to production the compiled files that has been changed.

The comparison fails if I do it in gated check-in because the source code is retreived again on the next gated check-in -> the binary is different (contains the compilation date) -> the binary is copied again to the production folder

Comment: Since your gated check-in build failed, the changes won't be checked in, the CI build won't be triggered is expected. Why do you still want a CI build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In the xaml build file, the step getting the source code from TFS has an option named "nocioption".

By default, this value is set to true, preventing CI builds to be triggered...